# Jquery - use one function for multiple id's to save on duplicate code

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, optimization, duplicates

I am not very good at creating efficient code so was hoping somebody could give some advice.

This is a very basic example of my question.
I have a form with two text fields and two select boxes:

```
<input type="text" name="phone1" id="phone1" />
<select id="p1_format">
    <option value="Landline">Land Line Number</option>
    <option value="Mobile">Mobile</option>
</select>
<div id="p1info"></div>

<input type="text" name="phone2" id="phone2" />
<select id="p2_format">
    <option value="Landline">Land Line Number</option>
    <option value="Mobile">Mobile</option>
</select>
<div id="p2info">
```

I am using a jquery plugin to apply a mask to the input boxes.
The user selects a number type from the select box to ensure the correct mask. Onchange it then applies the mask and writes a basic description to the div html.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#p1_format').change(function(){

        if($(this).val() =="LandLine"){
            $("#phone1").mask("+61 9 9999-9999");
            $('#p1info').html("Format: +61 8 XXXX-XXXX");
        }


        if($(this).val() =="Mobile"){            
        $("#phone1").mask("9999 999-999");
        $('#p1info').html("Format: XXXX XXX-XXX");
        }

    });
});
```

This all works well, but I have had to duplicate the above jquery function to deal with phone2 and change all the id values to #p2_format, #phone2 & #p2info.

Is there a way to use the one function by sending $("#thispart") as a variable? Or how else can I reuse the code rather than duplicate it?

Does my question make sense?
Appreciate your help.

Comment: Is it OK to change the HTML a little bit to make it easier to work with more generic JS?

Comment: So your formats will be `#phone1` to `#phone2` and `#p1info` to `#p2info`? In that case, you could use a for loop and use `$('#phone' + i)` and `$('#p' + i + 'info')` :)

Comment: @nnnnnn what can you suggest?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a general principle, I'd suggest using a single event handler bound to all of the select elements, and then use DOM navigation to get from the particular select element that the event occurred on to its related input and div.

So for your particular HTML structure you can use the [`.prev()`](http://api.jquery.com/prev/) and [`.next()`](http://api.jquery.com/next/) methods:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#p1_format, #p2_format').change(function(){
        var input = $(this).prev();
        var div = $(this).next();

        if(this.value =="LandLine"){
            input.mask("+61 9 9999-9999");
            div.html("Format: +61 8 XXXX-XXXX");
        } else if(this.value =="Mobile"){            
            input.mask("9999 999-999");
            div.html("Format: XXXX XXX-XXX");
        }
    });
});
```

Note that I've change the initial selector to `'#p1_format, #p2_format'` to apply the change handler to both select elements. It would be neater to give those elements a common class.

Of course this means that if you were to change the structure of your HTML you'd need to change your JS to handle the new structure. But one way of minimising that issue is to wrap the related elements in container divs and use classes:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.phoneFormat').change(function(){
        var container = $(this).closest(".phone");
        var input = container.find("input");
        var info = container.find(".phoneInfo");

        if(this.value =="Landline"){
            input.val("+61 9 9999-9999");
            info.html("Format: +61 8 XXXX-XXXX");
        } else if(this.value =="Mobile"){            
            input.val("9999 999-999");
            info.html("Format: XXXX XXX-XXX");
        }
    }).trigger("change");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="phone">
  <input type="text" name="phone1" />
  <select class="phoneFormat">
    <option value="Landline">Land Line Number</option>
    <option value="Mobile">Mobile</option>
  </select>
  <div class="phoneInfo"></div>
</div>
<div class="phone">
  <input type="text" name="phone2" />
  <select class="phoneFormat">
    <option value="Landline">Land Line Number</option>
    <option value="Mobile">Mobile</option>
  </select>
  <div class="phoneInfo"></div>
</div>
```

In the JS, I've used the [`.closest()`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) to get from the changed select up to its container, then used the [`.find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find/) method to select the input and info divs inside that container. This means you could move the select to before the input and not need to change the JS at all.

Note that I changed `.mask()` to `.val()` for *demo purposes only* so that when you run the above snippet you can easily see it working (without me having to figure out how to get the `.mask()` plugin to work in the snippet).

Note also that in your current code you are testing the value `"LandLine"` with a capital "L" in "Line", but in your HTML you have `value="Landline"` with a lowercase "l" in "line" - these need to match.

Comment: Wow! Thanks heaps! That is a great answer and very well explained. I have learned something new with this example. Legend!

Comment: You're welcome. I just added something to my second example that may help too: I've chained `.trigger("change");` on the end of the `.change()` handler. That means that the change handler will be called immediately after it is bound, for all `'.phoneFormat'` elements, so then the default format will be applied to the inputs when the page loads instead of waiting for the user to change the dropdown.

Comment: Ok, cool. I added the trigger part to my code. Certainly works better than what I was doing. I seem to take the long way to achieve the simplest things. But then again, it is just a lack of understanding on my part still. This has been a great help. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

You can use attribute ends with selector, `.prev()` and `.next()` to select previous `<input>` element and next `<div>` element

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('[id$=_format').change(function(){

        if($(this).val() =="LandLine"){
          $(this).prev("[id^=phone]").mask("+61 9 9999-9999");
          $(this).next("[id$=info]").html("Format: +61 8 XXXX-XXXX");
        }

        if($(this).val() =="Mobile"){            
          $(this).prev("[id^=phone]").mask("9999 999-999");
          $(this).next("[id$=info]").html("Format: XXXX XXX-XXX");
        }

    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You may add the duplicating code to a separate function as shown below.

```
function format(field, phone, info){
  if($(field).val() =="LandLine"){
    $(phone).mask("+61 9 9999-9999");
    $(info).html("Format: +61 8 XXXX-XXXX");
  }
  if(field.val() =="Mobile"){            
    $(phone).mask("9999 999-999");
    $(info).html("Format: XXXX XXX-XXX");
  }
}


$('#p1_format').change(function(){
 format($(this), $("#phone1"), $("#p1info"));
}
```

Here I have added some method parameters to describe the answer. Likewise, you may use a function to prevent the code duplication.
This way is very easy to understand and improves maintainability and reusability.